# What is the best way to create augmentation on image dataset while training instance segmentation?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, image-segmentation

I am using YOLACT instance segmentation model to train set of images. The dataset size is very small (~20 images). The model doesn't converge properly (of-course given the dataset size). I wanted to increase the dataset size by adding some augmented images. I know we have various image augmentation techniques and packages like imgaug , albumentation, opencv etc. but I need image & annotation file (COCO JSON ) format to train the model.

Is there a package that helps me to automatically generate the annotations of augmented images?

or is there a better way to address my issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Simple Copy Paste` is a strong method for data augmentation for instance segmentation related tasks.

Check about the research paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.07177).

For unofficial github code, check [here](https://github.com/conradry/copy-paste-aug)

`Albumentation` and `TorMentor` are also useful libraries for data augmentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator